# Scrolling in C++ Builder RadioGroup

Tags: c++, scrollbar, c++builder, vcl, radio-group

I have RadioGroup with many buttons. Now when I add an item, they become smaller and smaller. How is it possible to make them scrollable?

Answer (score 3):

`TRadioGroup` does not natively support scrolling.  However, what you can do instead is the following:

1. place a `TGroupBox` on your UI.
2. place a `TScrollBox` onto the `TGroupBox`, set its `Align` property to `alClient`, and its `BorderStyle` property to `bsNone`.
3. place a `TRadioGroup` onto the `TScrollBox`, clear its `Caption` property, and set its `Left` property to `-2` and its `Top` property to `-15` (or whatever the `TRadioGroup.Font` is set to plus a few extra pixels). This positioning is needed because you cannot turn off the `TRadioGroup`'s borders or the space reserved for its `Caption`.
4. Tweak the `TScrollBox.HorzScrollBar.Range` and `TScrollBox.VertScrollBar.Range` properties so they do not scroll far enough to see the `TRadioGroup`'s right and bottom borders.

This way, the buttons appear as if they are part of the `TGroupBox`, but with the added scrollbar(s).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

1. `RadioGroup->Items->Count`
2. `TRadioGroup` component doesn't have an embedded scrollbar, but you can put the radio group on a [`TScrollBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TScrollBox) for a similar effect.

   You can use the `Buttons` collection to refer each button, e.g.

   ```
   RadioGroup->Buttons[0]->Height = 5;
   RadioGroup->Buttons[1]->Top = RadioGroup->Buttons[0]->Top + 10;
   ```

   Anyway a `TComboBox` could also be a good choice.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i don't understand what is a button,i created RadioGroup1 and added Items using add() method, but when i used RadioGroup1->Buttons[0]->Height = 5; i got error: Height is not a member of TString

Comment: [Buttons](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomRadioGroup.Buttons) provides direct access to the individual [TRadioButton](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TRadioButton) objects created by the control. You can access individual `TRadioButton` objects, but you cannot add or delete `TRadioButton` objects (to modify the button list, change the `Items` property).